# Bash: How to tail then copy multiple files (eg using xargs)?

Tags: linux, bash, find, tail, xargs

I've been trying various combinations of xargs and piping but I just can't get the right result. Previous questions don't quite cover exactly what I want to do:

- I have a source directory somewhere, lets say /foo/source, with a mix of different files
- I want to copy just the csv files found in source to a different destination, say /foo/dest
- But I ALSO at the same time need to remove 232 header rows (eg using tail)

I've figured out that I need to pipe the results of find into xargs, which can then run commands on each find result. But I'm struggling to tail then copy. If I pipe tail into cp, cp does not seem to receive the file (missing file operand). Here's some examples of what I've tried so far:

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 | cp -t /foo/dest'
```

> cp: missing file operand

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 {} | cp -t /foo/dest'
```

Result:

> cp: failed to access '/foo/dest': No such file or directory ...

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 {} > /foo/dest/{}'
```

> sh: /foo/dest/foo/source/0001.csv: No such file or directory ...

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last command is close, but the problem is that `{}` is replaced with the full pathname, not just the filename. Use the `basename` command to extract the filename from it.

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 {} > /foo/dest/$(basename {})'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was playing with basename but just couldn't get the syntax right! Massive help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use `find` with `exec` and copy the file name in a variable:

```
find your_dir -name "*.csv" -exec sh -c 'f="$1"; tail -n +5 "$f" > dest_dir/$(basename "$f")' -- {} \;
```

See `f={}` makes `$f` hold the name of the file, with the full path. Then, it is a matter of redirecting the output of `tail` into the file, stripping the path from it.

Or, based on [Random832's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350420/bash-how-to-tail-then-copy-multiple-files-eg-using-xargs/39350500#comment66033137_39350500) below in comments (thanks!):

```
find your_dir -name "*.csv" -exec sh -c 'tail -n +5 "$1" > dest_dir/$(basename "$1")' -- {} \;
```

Comment: @JamesAllen ok, now I found another way using `-exec`.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, Barmar just beat you to it using xargs and basename. Thanks though!

Comment: @JamesAllen yep, I always wonder what is best, to pipe to `xargs` or use `-exec`. I prefer the latter, but both ways should be equivalent in most of the cases.

Comment: This use of exec will not work correctly with filenames that may contain space or other special characters. Use `-exec sh -c 'f="$1"; ...' -- {} \;` (or just use `"$1"` throughout the shell command and don't use a `$f` variable)

Comment: @Random832 wo, that's a great hint. Would you mind explaining why is `--` making it work? Updated the answer, many thanks.

Comment: @fedorqui I actually discovered the need for it by accident and assumed it was always required, but it turns out that the first argument after `-c '...'` gets put in $0. But $0 has a special meaning so I wouldn't recommend using it just to be able to omit the -- argument.

Comment: @Random832 ah, I see. So by saying `sh -c '...' -- {} \;` we are passing `--` as the first argument ($0), {} as the second one ($1) and so on, cool! For example `find aaa -name "*.csv" -exec sh -c 'echo $2, $3;' -- -- a b \;`  returns `a, b`. I wasn't aware of the way `sh -c` was getting its arguments.

Comment: @Random832 because in fact this also happens when you say `bash -c 'echo "$1"' "var1" "var2"`. It will print var2 - I don't like this inconsistency of `$0` :/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to find and xargs you could use a for loop, and as an alternative to tail you could use sed, consider this:

```
source=/foo/source
dest=/foo/dest
for csv in $source/*.csv; do sed '232,$ !d' $csv > $dest/$(basename $csv); done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you would do:

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | parallel tail -n +232 {} '>' /foo/dest/{/}
```