# Using xargs basename in Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, substitution, xargs

I have a working solution from [an earlier question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350420/bash-how-to-tail-then-copy-multiple-files-eg-using-xargs) for finding csv files in a source directory (/foo/source), chopping off the first 233 lines using tail, and saving that to a file in a different directory (/foo/dest):

```
find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 {} > /foo/dest/$(basename {})'
```

This works great when run as-is in bash.

My problem is the exact same command in a Makefile target fails:

```
copyfiles:
    find /foo/source -name "*.csv" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'tail -n +232 {} > /foo/dest/$(basename {})'

make copyfiles
```

> sh: /foo/dest//foo.source/somecsv.csv: No such file or directory

It seems that the basename command is no longer working when in Make, as it is just using the whole path + filename of the source file when saving.

Why is this happening, and is there a way around this? Is there a simpler way to achieve what I'm doing? I need to search a folder for csv files, tail, then save into a different location.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html Assume subshells with `$` are vars.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @123. Sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @123 for a hint, I managed to answer my question: use `$$(basename {})`.